# [WSO2][ESB] Could not build deploy CAR file with PROPERTY mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

There seems to be an error while trying to build a REST API.
My REST API has a custom mediator:

```
        <class name="my.com.tm.myipcs.custom.mediator.ValidateHeader">
            <property name="source" expression="get-property('source')"/>
        </class>
```

Yet when I save it, the Developer Studio shows an error as below:

Unknown synapse configuration tag:

At line 18,

I am using Eclipse Mars. and the WSO2 ESB Server 5.0.0 is my server.
Can some one suggest a workaround or better a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your custom mediator implement ListMediator (or FilterMediator)?  If not and it is a LeafMediator it cannot contain child mediators.

Comment: I have not. However I did extend AbstractMediator to build the custom mediator.

Comment: Hi, I did try to implement the ListMediator but it still showed the same error.